# What are model sheets and why do animators use them?

Tags: anime-production

Model sheets depict characters in their front view, side view, behind, and facial expressions, etc. In anime production animators use these, but what does it contribute in trying to animate?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: i don't know, but it looks like concept art to me. this means that the animators create these drawings to orient themselves, when they draw the clean ones. this guarantees (at least to some degree) that the characters look consistently like themselves, independent of who drew them.

Comment: I need a proper answer to this question, that is not good enough

Comment: well, since you asked this here, I thought there would be little information on the internet, but a simple Google query answered it. Please do some research, before asking. My answer lists two sites that I found after searching for 'model sheet'.

Answer (score 3):

Like I already guessed in the comments, model sheets are used to guarantee consistency in character design.

They are a concept art to define the character design. In big teams, you have the problem that everyone sees the character a bit different, so they try to standardize the design by creating a model.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_sheet#Purposes)

[Another site](http://www.awn.com/tooninstitute/lessonplan/model.htm)

Comment: So its simply to keep animators from drawing the characters in their own artstyles?

Comment: @user18661 yes, thus improving the consistency of the depiction of characters